# How can I calculate $a^m - a^n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there any way, by which I can calculate $a^m-a^n$?  I'm aware of the other existing laws of exponents, but I couldn't find one for this. If there exists any handy formula for the same, can anyone please derive it.

Comment: Try for example $2^7-2^5$. What do you see?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, taking a smaller example, $2^3 - 2^2 = 4$, and 4 can be written as $2^2$. So, is it equal to $a^n$?

Comment: No, take $2^7-2^5=96=2^5\cdot 3$. We have a new prime factor $3$. So a formula must be more complicated than that.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, sir i didn't get it yet!

Comment: Factor out the smaller exponent

Comment: 5 is smaller exponent. So, factoring it will result in 5,1 as it's factors.

Comment: if you call $r=\min(m,n)$ you could write $a^m-a^n=a^r(a^{m-r}-a^{n-r})$

Comment: Hence, this is the formula @cand ?

Comment: What do you mean by "calculating $a^m-a^n$"?  You figure out what $a^m$ is and what $a^n$ is and you subtract them.  If you what some way to simplify the expression if $n < m$ the $a^m-a^n= a^n(a^{n-m}-1)=a^n(a^{n-m-1}+a^{n-m-2}+...+1)$.  And for any $p|n-m$ we may also factor $a^{n-m}-1$ as $(a^p-1)(a^{n-m-p}+a^{n-m-2p}+...+1)$.  But that doesn't necessarily help you *calculate* $a^n-a^m$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no general rule for simplifying that difference. If you encounter it on an elementary algebra quiz there is probably some particular context that helps.

There are ways to rewrite the difference, but they probably don't mean what you mean by "calculate".

When $m>n$ you can factor
$$
a^m - a^n = a^{n}(a^{m-n} -1)
$$
and then continue with 
$$
a^t - 1 = (a-1)(a^{t-1} + a^{t-2}   +\cdots + 1),
$$
(using $t = m-n$).